# Android getting values from intent

Tags: android, android-intent

Below shown is the code, i am using to get values from the intent

```
  Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
```

extras object has the follwoing information

```
Bundle[{message=Order #400000063 is Ready for pickup, android.support.content.wakelockid=2, collapse_key=do_not_collapse, from=552489062080, e_id=364}]
```

When I say

```
extras.getString("message");
```

returns null. I am not sure how to get the values ?

Comment: How are you passing the value ? can you upload the code ?

Comment: have you add Intent intent = getIntent(); beforoe getting extras..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Activity1:

```
        Intent i = new Intent(Activity1.this,Activity2.class);
        i.putExtra("message", "string_value");
        startActivity(i);
```

In your Activity2:

```
// do a try/catch block or check 
//if getIntent().getStringExtra("message") is null
String str = getIntent().getStringExtra("string_tag");
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are writing different tag name ..

Use the same tag name which you used while sending data with Intent.

while sending data if you used code as

```
Intent i = new Intent(Activity1.this,Activity2.class);
    i.putExtra("TAG_NAME", "string_value");
    startActivity(i);
```

then use code below as

String str = getIntent().getStringExtra("TAG_NAME");

try it...

Comment: purpose?? why copying my answer "nearly" the same with just different variable names :)

Comment: don't try to be smart. even activty names and str variable names are the same. you just changed tag part. and "even if" you wrote on your own, the answer was already given 10 minutes before you. just pointless ^^

Comment: When I saw there was no acceptance.. Anyways we are here to solve probs together nothing else...

Comment: what u wrote might be ur way n what i wrote was my way ok.. and if we are giving just example to others then do we have to think activity names or we will write generic name....